# use or and whereHas in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, conditional-statements

I have an orders table which contains 2 columns, user_id and unregistered_address. One of the columns has to be null as the user can either be registered with an address, or unregistered and just has address details.

Both user.address and unregistered_address are linked to a city. (user.address.city & unregistered_address.city)

I want to get the orders, for a specific cities, for both registered users and unregistered users. I am using eloquent's whereHas but it seems that when one of the two columns is null i get no results. This is my code:

```
 $orders = Order::whereHas('user.address', function($query) use ($cityIds){
                 $query->whereIn('city_id', $cityIds);
         })
         ->whereHas('unregisteredAddress', function ($query) use ($cityIds){
                 $query->whereIn('city_id', $cityIds);
        })-> with(['user.address','unregisteredAddress'])->get();
```

Can anyone help? thanks.

Comment: Use `orWhereHas` for the second clause: `->orWhereHas('unregisteredAddress', ...`.